# No output when runing csv file in kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle

Im following the first tutorial on kaggle in machine lerning

The code im using is this:

```
import pandas as pd

# save filepath to variable for easier access
melbourne_file_path = 'input/melb_data.csv'
# read the data and store data in DataFrame titled melbourne_data
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
# print a summary of the data in Melbourne data
melbourne_data.describe()
```

the file melb_data.csv is in the folder /input which is in the folder kaggle

in my kaggle folder is also the file tut1.py which includes above code.

when i run

```
python tut1.py
```

nothing happens - no error nothing

```
 -kaggle
    -tut1.py
            -/input - melb_data.csv
```

i installed pandas inside my kaggle folder with `pip install pandas`

How can i make this work?

i also tried to run it `python3 tut1.py`which also produces no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as it is supposed to. You don't see anything because you are not printing.

```
import pandas as pd

# save filepath to variable for easier access
melbourne_file_path = 'input/melb_data.csv'
# read the data and store data in DataFrame titled melbourne_data
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
# print a summary of the data in Melbourne data
print(melbourne_data.describe())
```

Comment: i know i ran it with the print function but how come it doesnt say anything about doing it like that on kaggles: 
https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/basic-data-exploration

Comment: and when running it using print it doesnt print out all the columns

Comment: and even when i run the code in the kaggle collab notebook, it doesnt use the print function, thatswhy im confused.
https://www.kaggle.com/codingjoe/exercise-explore-your-data/edit

Comment: notebooks are a little bit different from the python scripts. They have a few exclusive abilities like: to print out the last variable in a cell and decorate the dataframes while displaying